# Drag and draw rectangle and circle based on button pressed?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view

So I am trying to make an app that lets you drag and draw two different shapes on the same canvas by selecting the corresponding button for each shape, circle and rectangle. I have a custom view called drawing view and two buttons in my layout. The on click listener for each button puts a string in shared preferences indicating the shape that is selected. The view then draws the corresponding shape on the canvas as the user drags their finger. Here is my view class:

```
public class DrawingView extends View {
    private Box mCurrentBox;
    private List<Box> mBoxen = new ArrayList<>();
    private Paint mBoxPaint;

    private Circle mCurrentCircle;
    private List<Circle> mCirclen = new ArrayList<>();
    private Paint mCirclePaint;

    private Paint mBackgroundPaint;

    // Used when creating the view in code
    public DrawingView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    // Used when inflating the view from XML
    public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        // Paint the boxes a nice semitransparent red (ARGB)
        mBoxPaint = new Paint();
        mBoxPaint.setColor(0x22ff0000);

        mCirclePaint = new Paint();
        mCirclePaint.setColor(0x22ff0000);

        // Paint the background off-white
        mBackgroundPaint = new Paint();
        mBackgroundPaint.setColor(0xfff8efe0);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // Fill the background
        canvas.drawPaint(mBackgroundPaint);

        if (PreferencesHelper.getStoredShape(getContext()) == "box") {

            for (Box box : mBoxen) {
                float left = Math.min(box.getOrigin().x, box.getCurrent().x);
                float right = Math.max(box.getOrigin().x, box.getCurrent().x);
                float top = Math.min(box.getOrigin().y, box.getCurrent().y);
                float bottom = Math.max(box.getOrigin().y, box.getCurrent().y);

                canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, mBoxPaint);
            }
        }

        else if(PreferencesHelper.getStoredShape(getContext()) == "circle") {

            for (Circle circle : mCirclen) {
                float left = Math.min(circle.getOrigin().x, circle.getCurrent().x);
                float right = Math.max(circle.getOrigin().x, circle.getCurrent().x);
                float top = Math.min(circle.getOrigin().y, circle.getCurrent().y);
                float bottom = Math.max(circle.getOrigin().y, circle.getCurrent().y);

                float cx = circle.getOrigin().x;
                float cy = circle.getOrigin().y;

                float radius = (float) Math.sqrt((right - left) * (right - left) + (bottom - top) * (bottom - top));

                canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, radius, mCirclePaint);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        PointF current = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());
        String action = "";


        if (PreferencesHelper.getStoredShape(getContext()) == "box") {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    action = "ACTION_DOWN";
                    // Reset drawing state
                    mCurrentBox = new Box(current);
                    mBoxen.add(mCurrentBox);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    action = "ACTION_MOVE";
                    if (mCurrentBox != null) {
                        mCurrentBox.setCurrent(current);
                        invalidate();
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    action = "ACTION_UP";
                    mCurrentBox = null;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    action = "ACTION_CANCEL";
                    mCurrentBox = null;
                    break;
            }
        }
        else if (PreferencesHelper.getStoredShape(getContext()) == "circle") {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        action = "ACTION_DOWN";
                        // Reset drawing state
                        mCurrentCircle = new Circle(current);
                        mCirclen.add(mCurrentCircle);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        action = "ACTION_MOVE";
                        if (mCurrentCircle != null) {
                            mCurrentCircle.setCurrent(current);
                            invalidate();
                        }
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        action = "ACTION_UP";
                        mCurrentCircle = null;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                        action = "ACTION_CANCEL";
                        mCurrentCircle = null;
                        break;
                }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The functionality for drawing the two shapes works fine but the problem is that the app seems to have two different canvases for drawing the two different shapes. For example, when rectangle is selected you can drag and draw endless rectangles, but when you switch to circle it switches to a black canvas and lets you drag and draw endless circles. When you switch back to rectangle, it saves what was on the canvas from drawing rectangles and the same when you switch back to circle.

I want to be able to draw as many rectangles as I want onto the canvas and then switch to drawing circles on top of the already drawn rectangles. What is causing this to happen?

Comment: Here is an example http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2015/12/android-animations-explained.html

Comment: That deals with animation and not drawing on a view's canvas.

Comment: @cjones3724 When you start the application, and start drawing rectangles, does the canvas paint the correct off-white background? And you can draw multiple rectangles before you switch to circles?

Comment: @cjones3724 I had some issues when trying to draw to the view's canvas, what fixed a lot of rendering issues for me was when I switched to handling the drawing on my own canvas. I would draw all of the images on a separate bitmap, then draw that bitmap to the view's canvas in every `onDraw()`.

Comment: @Bryan could you give me an example of the code you used to implement that. I would gladly give you the best answer.

Comment: @cjones3724 I am working on posting some code, but I would like to understand what is going on in your code a little better. Would you be able to post your `PreferencesHelper` code? I think the reason you are not able to draw circle and squares at the same time is because you can only reach one of the two for loops in your `onDraw` method. I still don't know why it would draw a black background though.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I think you may be better off with a new model for your shapes. You can create a `Shape` interface with an `draw` method that will draw the shape to a canvas, then have your `Box` and `Circle` classes implement `Shape`. This way you can have a single `List<Shape>`, simplifying your logic.

```
public interface Shape {

    void setOrigin(float x, float y);

    void setTerminal(float x, float y);

    void draw(Canvas canvas);
}
```

---

```
public class Box implements Shape {

    private PointF mOrigin;
    private PointF mTerminal;

    private Paint mPaint;

    public Box(Paint paint) {
        mPaint = paint;
    }

    public void setOrigin(float x, float y) {
        mOrigin = new PointF(x, y);
    }

    public void setTerminal(float x, float y) {
        mTerminal = new PointF(x, y);
    }

    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        float left = Math.min(mOrigin.x, mTerminal.x);
        float right = Math.max(mOrigin.x, mTerminal.x);
        float top = Math.min(mOrigin.y, mTerminal.y);
        float bottom = Math.max(mOrigin.y, mTerminal.y);

        canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, mPaint);
    }
}
```

Then in `onDraw` you can just call the draw methods of all of the `Shape` objects in your `List`:

```
private Shape mCurrentShape;
private List<? extends Shape> mShapes;

...

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawPaint(mBackgroundPaint);

    for(Shape shape : mShapes) {
        shape.draw(canvas);
    }

    mCurrentShape.draw(canvas);
}
```

I think this may simplify some of your logic, and enable you to draw multiple shapes on a single canvas. Though, as I stated in a comment, I do not know if this will fix the black background you are getting.